# How do I make control characters programatically in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, special-characters

In Javascript I can type `'\u00A3'` to get a character using its char code. I can do this programatically to with `String.fromCharCode(parseInt('00A3', 16))`.

But I can't find a way to do the same for a control character. I can type them in my source code but I want a way to generate them in code.

Comment: ?? But "control" characters are just characters; if you know the numeric value for the character, you use "fromCharCode()" in exactly the same way.

Comment: I know the numeric value for \u00A3, but not for Ctrl + B. I have to look it up. I was wondering if there was a way Javascript could look that up for me.

Comment: Control characters "Control A" through "Control Z" are just characters 1 through 26 (decimal); in other words, Ctrl-A is 0x0001, Ctrl-B is 0x0002, etc.  Thus, you could find the code for the letter ("A") and subtract 64 from its code value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds to me like you could just use this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes and use the character points defined there to insert them with `\u` or `String.fromCharCode` as in your example?

PS: instead of the `parseInt`, you could use a literal: `0x00A3`

Answer (score 3):

You can easily embed octal numbers:

```
var crlf = '\013' + '\012'; // octal numbers
alert('hello' + crlf + 'there'); // shows hello\n\rthere
```

Doesn't work the same for hex, though:

```
var clrf = '\0xD' + '\0xA'; // hex
alert('hello' + crlf + 'there'); // shows helloxDxAthere
```

Comment: Octal escape sequences are not standard and disallowed in "strict" mode.  Hex escape sequences look like `\0x000D`, with four-digit hex values.