# Prevent pasting wrong values into Input number type

Tags: javascript, html, input, types, numbers

I have an Input element with type = "number", which is supposed to only accept 0,1,..,9 and "."
Per default you can also wrie +, - ans soem other characters which I prevent with EventListener "keydown" and keyCodes. It works fine.

But how can I prevent the user from pasting or drag and dropping some other stuff into the input? I tried to validate input.value but it actually gives me "" when it is not a valid number. 
Is there a way to see what the user wants to paste, before it is pasted?

I also know, that I could change the type to "text", but at leas for now it is not an option.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use the [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) to handle this.

Comment: use the pattern attribute to only accept 0-9. Use a `min="0"` to prevent negative numbers. Sure they can enter in invalid characters but the form will be invalid and prevent a submit

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reject any input other than `0-9` and `.`, try this:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('restricted')).forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('input', event => {
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="restricted">
```

You can add `.restricted` to any input to achieve the same effect once this script is in place. Unfortunately, this trick won’t work with `input[type="number"]`, because `event.target.value` is `''` whenever an invalid input state is detected.

Answer (score 1):

Without javascript

```css
:invalid {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="https://httpbin.org/post">
  <input type="number" name="num" pattern="[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+" min="0" step="any">
  <!-- you won't be able to submit when the form is invalid -->
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PS (browser take care of normalizing the `,` to `.`)

Answer (score 0):

try this event:

Pasting:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste

Draging:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag

maybe look at this:

[How do I make control characters programatically in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386907/how-do-i-make-control-characters-programatically-in-javascript)

**EDIT:**

```
document.getElementById('id').addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
  let pre = e.target.value;
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(pre);
    console.log(e.target.value);
    /*
    Get the pasted value here, and edit the input
    */
  });
});
```

Comment: How will either of those events help if someone just types the wrong number in, or wants to paste a correct one?

Comment: What if I just click in the text field and type `+`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

> It allows you to use any kind of input filter on a text ,
>   including various numeric filters. This will correctly handle
>   Copy+Paste, Drag+Drop, keyboard shortcuts, context menu operations,
>   non-typeable keys, and all keyboard layouts.

```js
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input name="someid" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>
```

Comment: How will either of those events help if someone just types the wrong number in, or wants to paste a correct one?

Comment: I add for "paste", too

Comment: Check, i fix it

Comment: No, you haven’t. I can still paste an invalid value into that input

Comment: What do you paste?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188433/discussion-between-artee-and-mtcoster).

Answer (score 0):

I have countered something similar, i used regex to filter the entered value of any characters only accepts numbers. the down side to this solution is that it only accept integer numbers not numeric. here is a code example:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
    if (e.target.value === '' || re.test(e.target.value)) {
         this.setState({Number: e.target.value})
      }
  }
```

I'm using reactjs for this example, but of course you can adjust the code to serve your purpose